# AutoMapper recognize prefixes with dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I installed the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection nuget package and I am using .NET Core 3.1. According to the documentation (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) I should be able to add prefixes to my property names. But when I map my two classes the properties with the prefix are null. I have an abstract class with several properties that are extended to my UserDto model I then map the UserDto model to my UserEntity model which does not have an abstract class. My UserEntity model uses the prefix User for every propery, e.g. UserId, UserName, whilst my UserDto just uses Id, Name, etc. I register AutoMapper and add my configuration as follows:

```
        #region Auto Mapper
        services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
        {
            config.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "User", "Role", "Language" });
            config.AddProfile(new DtoToEntityProfile());
            config.AddProfile(new ContractToDtoProfile());

        }, typeof(Startup));
        #endregion
```

I added my profiles to the config to see if this would work. Before Automapper could also automatically find my profiles by scanninng the Assembly. What do I have to do to map my Dto to my Entity model without mapping every single property manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the functions and Properties in the Profile class of Auto Mapper I discovered there is a RecognizePrefixes and a RecognizeDestinationPrefixes function the RecognizePrefixes function only removes the prefixes from the source and the RecognizeDestinationPrefixes function only removes prefixes from the destination.

RecognizePrefixes is kind of a misleading name that way. I fixed my issue by implementing my config as follows:

```
        #region Auto Mapper
        services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
        {
            config.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new[] { "User", "Role", "Domain", "Language" });
            config.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "User", "Role", "Domain", "Language" });

        }, typeof(Startup));
        #endregion
```